# jQuery elements are dynamically added to the DOM tree but they do not interact correctly with JS code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, socket.io

To summarize the concept of the app being built, it is a live card game using socket.io between two players. (For the current playtest build, a game is created when two browsers are open: for example two browsers open to 'http://localhost:8000/', the first browser representing 'player 1' and the second being 'player 2') Each player has a finite number of cards within their hand from which they choose from, and each player has their own respective battlefield where cards are sent to when played.

For each card element displayed in the DOM, there is a zoom-in feature and an actionable cards menu that appear when a card is clicked/hovered upon.

The following code demonstrates this functionality:

```
// 'cards' is a jQuery Object containing all card elements with class '.hasCard'
let cards = $('.hasCard');

// The click event listener is for initializing the actionable cards menu
cards.off('click').on('click', function() {
  initializeActionableCards($(this));
});

// .mouseover()/.mouseout() is for the zoom-in feature and dynamically adding a few other elements to the current card being hovered over 
cards.mouseover(function() {

  //more code here

}).mouseout(function() {

  //more code here

});
```

But, the problem I am having is when dynamically added card elements are added to a player's screen. These dynamically added elements do not function the same as "player 1's" cards, and I have yet to discover a solid reason why. As a result, the zoom-in feature and actionable cards menu mentioned above do not appear when these elements are clicked/hovered upon.

I will try to help visualize the issue with an example: a dynamically created card element would take place if 'player 2' were to play a card to their own battlefield. In order to display to 'player 1' that this card was played, the card would need to be dynamically added to the DOM of 'player 1' in the 'player2Field'  below. (This is all being communicated between client/server using socket.io)

```
<div id="battlefield">
  <div id="player2Field" class="playerCards player2Field">

    // Whatever card 'player 2' plays would be dynamically added here
    // Zoom-in feature/actionable cards menu does not appear for these card elements

  </div>
  <div id="player1Field" class="playerCards player1Field">

  // Any of "player 1's" cards would be displayed here
  // Zoom-in feature/actionable cards menu appear for these cards

  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, "player 2's" cards are programmed to be dynamically added to "player 1's" DOM within the 'player2Field'  using the following block of code (I am including it for the sake of review purposes as there may be unforeseen issues):

```
// 'player2Field' is an Array with "player 2's" current cards in play
// For each iteration, a new element 'currCard' is created with the current card's image, id, etc.

for (let i = 0; i < player2Field.length; i++) {
  let currCard = $('<div/>');
      currCard.addClass('hasCard highlight');
      currCard.css('background-image', 'url(img/' + player2Field[i].image + ')');
      currCard.attr('id', 'opp-' + player2Field[i].cardId);
      currCard.attr('onclick', 'selectOpponentCard(this.id)');
      currCard.appendTo('.player2Field');
}
```

While doing my own research on the issue, I discovered a potentially useful Node.property '.isConnected'. For all of "player 1's" cards, whether they be in the player's hand or on the battlefield, have a '.isConnected' value of 'true.' On the other hand, the 'player 2' cards that are dynamically added have a '.isConnected' value of 'false.' This may be the issue as the '.isConnected' property displays whether an element is connected to the DOM tree or not.

The following output is from a console.log(cards) statement('cards' is the element set equal to a jQuery selector from above), which is outputting all the card elements in the DOM tree. Oddly enough, "player 2's" cards seem to be added to the DOM and appear so on the screen, but none of the JavaScript (when I say JavaScript I am referring to the code for the zoom-in/actionable menu features) is able to interact with these elements.

```
0: div#opp-one12.hasCard.highlight

attributes: NamedNodeMap(4) [ class="hasCard highlight", style="background-image: url(\"img/scryb-sprites.jpg\");", id="opp-one12", … ]
isConnected: false


1: div#one14.hasCard.highlight.ui-sortable-handle.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle
​​
attributes: NamedNodeMap(4) [ class="hasCard highlight ui-sortable-handle ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle", style="background-image: url(\"img/scryb-sprites.jpg\"); border: 2px solid white;", onclick="selectOnField(this.id)", … ]
isConnected: true
```

I will continue debugging this issue to the best of my ability on my own, but could definitely use a few more eyes on it. Thanks.